Is it possible to see a complete list of const or let variables?
I'm writing a piece of JavaScript code which will be used on any Instagram POSTS page (the landing page of an Instagram user). After pasting my code into the console and hitting Enter, the code needs to get all posts that have been loaded.
I noticed that, after scrolling down the page for some distance, the previously loaded posts disappear from DOM. And after scrolling back up, those posts re-appear in DOM. I think the data of those posts are most likely stored in a variable for quick access because I have seen a similar social media doing that.
I checked the window global variable and didn't find any such variable under it. The variable (if there is one) must have been a const or let variable then. Is there a way to see a complete list of const or let variables so that I can try to dig out the data of posts from them?

From the Instagram terms of service:  You can’t modify, translate, create derivative works of, or reverse engineer our products or their components.

Is it possible to see a complete list of const or let variables? No, you can't. Even if you could, it wouldn't be helpful. This is probably an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

@HaoWu Thanks for letting know it's not possible. As for my reasons, I need the data of posts so that I can download those videos in bulk.

You're wrong. If you scroll down a long way, then scroll up, the posts are re-fetched from the server. I guess instagram doesn't really want to make it easy for people like you to borrow its resources in bulk like that

@JaromandaX Thanks, so it's all Ajax. I wondered about that because I saw data transactions in the Network tab when I scrolling down/up but I wasn't very about what data those were.
